# How to integrate AngularJs theme into django?

Tags: angularjs, django

I have very basic knowledge about angularjs and django. I want to develop a web application using django, angular and Postgre SQL as a database. I have an angularjs theme and i want to integrate it with django.

Answer (score 0):

Actually there's nothing special to do. If when you say *theme* you mean a HTML/CSS pack, you won't have problems to use it whith a django backend, just follow the [Django's documentation for templates](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/ref/templates/language/#templates).